# OnSubmit não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html

Estou verificando um form com o `onsubmit`, porém mesmo retornando `true` ele da o submit.
Segue a função que chama no onsubmit:

```
function checkFormModal(){
        var senhaAtual = document.getElementById("senhaAtu").value;
        var alerta = document.getElementById("avisoSenhaDig");
        var usuario = document.getElementById("nomeUsuarioTestaSenha").value;
        var p = document.getElementById("p");
        var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

        xmlreq.open("GET", "../Controller/verificaSenhaUsuario.php?senha="+senhaAtual+"&nomeusu="+usuario, true);

        xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
              if (xmlreq.responseText == "nao") {
                if (senhaAtual.length > 0) {
                  return false;
                }
                return false;
              }else if (xmlreq.responseText == "sim"){
                p.innerHTML = "true";
                return true;
              }
            }else{
              alerta.innerHTML = "ERRO: " + xmlreq.statusText;
              return false;
            }
          }
        };
        xmlreq.send(null);
        return false;

      }
```

É para ele retornar true apenas se o resposeText for sim, ele entra no if que verifica isso(ele da o innerHTML no p) porém mesmo assim ele não da o submit no form.
Segue abaixo o form e como é feito o OnSubmit:

```
<form name="formSenha" role="form" onsubmit="return checkFormModal()" class="form" action="../Controller/editaSenhaUsuario.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

Gostaria de saber o porque ele não dar return true. Grato desde já.

Comment: Não há nenhum tratamento para que ocorra a action, apenas o pressionar do botão `submit`.

Você esta utilizando Ajax. então tenta colocar o atributo action vazio e redirecionar com o javascript..

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti, colocar o action do botao submit vazio? Porque clicando no botão é a única forma de dar o submit neste form.

Comment: Você sabe que o formulário irá submeter caso seja retornado true, né?

Comment: sim, e é exatamente isso que não está ocorrendo. Ele da o innerHTML no p, ou seja, entrou no if que da return true, e mesmo assim ele não da o submit

Comment: Deixe seu onsubmit assim: `onsubmit="return checkFormModal()"`

Comment: já tinha chegado a fazer essa edição, porém continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Onde está a função `CriaRequest()`?

Comment: está no mesmo arquivo, porém não a coloquei aqui porque a princípio está funcionando esta parte. Se tu julgares necessário eu posso editar a pergunta e colocar esta função junto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não vai poder usar o submit do formulário com Ajax porque ambos são assíncronos. Quando você faz o submit, toda a função é executada antes do processamento do Ajax, ou seja, antes que o Ajax seja processado, o último `return false` já foi enviado de volta. Só depois o Ajax entra no `if` com `true`, mas aí já é tarde porque a função já fez o retorno de `false`.

Neste caso, você terá que fazer um submit manual após o processamento do Ajax. Você precisa enviar o form via `this` no `onsubmit` desta forma:

```
onsubmit="return checkFormModal(this)"
```

E incluir um parâmetro na função:

```
function checkFormModal(form){...
```

A variável `form` será o elemento do formulário dentro da função. Ao meu ver, todo aqueles if's verificando `nao` e vários returns false se tornam desnecessários, deixando apenas o último `return false` para que o formulário não seja submetido ao chamar a função.

Reformulando a função, ela ficaria assim, fazendo um submit quando o retorno do Ajax for `sim`:

```
function checkFormModal(form){

        var senhaAtual = document.getElementById("senhaAtu").value;
        var alerta = document.getElementById("avisoSenhaDig");
        var usuario = document.getElementById("nomeUsuarioTestaSenha").value;
        var p = document.getElementById("p");
        var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

        xmlreq.open("GET", "../Controller/verificaSenhaUsuario.php?senha="+senhaAtual+"&nomeusu="+usuario, true);

        xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
              if (xmlreq.responseText == "sim"){
                p.innerHTML = "true";
                form.submit();
              }
            }else{
              alerta.innerHTML = "ERRO: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
          }
        };
        xmlreq.send(null);

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, pensei que ao retornar `true` ele já iria dar o submit. Obrigado!

Comment: Se não tivesse Ajax iria funcionar o true. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi o que você quer fazer, o que você precisa é que seu método `checkFormModal()` retorne `true` ou `false`, e no caso de `false` a página não seja enviada.

Se for isso o que você precisa fazer é algo como isso aqui.

```
<form action="/*pagina*/" onsubmit="return checkFormModal(this)" method="post">

 /***Seus inputs***/
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: está desta maneira, a única diferença é que esta `<button type="submit">Confirmar</button>`, mesmo assim mudei para ver se funcionava, porém continua sem dar o submit ao pressionar o botão, quando o return é true.

Comment: O que acontece quando você pressiona `submit` ?

Comment: Nada, parece que retornou false, porém ele deu o innerHTML de teste, ou seja, ele entra no if correto.